# Does the following function have any poles or zeros?

Tags: complex-analysis, gamma-function

$F(x)=\int_1^\infty t^xe^{-t}dt$

It doesn't look like the function has any zeros or poles on the complex plane, but I'm curious if there are.

Comment: Since $e^{-t}$ tends to $0$ at a far greater rate than $t^x$ tends to infinity, regardless of the $x$ as $t\to\infty$, the integral is convergent for bounds $[1,\infty]$

Answer (score 1):

Your integral is the upper [incomplete Gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function) $\Gamma(x+1,1)$.  This is an entire function, so no poles.  There are zeros, presumably infinitely many, of which the closest to $0$ are approximately $1.772122006 \pm 4.398958636 i$.

Here is a plot of the curves $\text{Re}(\Gamma(z+1,1) = 0$ (blue)
and $\text{Im}(\Gamma(z+1,1) = 0$ (red) in part of the complex plane.  The zeros are the intersections of red and blue curves.

[image]